# itext pdf image is not showing

Tags: java, pdf, itextpdf

I use itextpdf version 5.5.5 and I want to show image on the pdf. The API I use is **com.itextpdf.text.Image** and the input for constructor is an **InputStream**

> Image image = Image.getInstance(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputstream));

The problem is that the image doesn't diplay but I still can read the **attributes** of the image like **width** and **height** and others ...

Those attributes are correctly displayed.

Any advise for this issue really appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding the image to a document? If not, it's only normal that it doesn't show up. If so, how are you adding it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie yes I add the image to a document. I add image to a Paragraph and Paragraph added to document

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @TruongMai As I can't see you adding it and as you say it's not aďded, I can only say; you are doing it the wrong way. Please do it the right way.

Comment: @TruongMai Did you fixed this issue ?